# Objective C, Audio Player volume was suddenly reduced

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I don't know when it exactly happens, but sometimes audio volume becomes very low. I think this may happen when I play recored sound.

I record user's voice, and then play it immediately after. Volume is okay when other mp3 files are played, but it sometimes becomes very low when I play the recorded sound. At this time, sound seems like playing around iphone's ear phone pin area, so the sound seems like one-sided sound.

Following is recording function.

```
- (void)startRecording {
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
if(err) {
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %ld %@", [err domain], (long)[err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}

[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
err = nil;
if(err) {
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %ld %@", [err domain], (long)[err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}

recorderSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recorderSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recorderSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recorderSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recorderSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recorderSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[recorderSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];

// Create a new audio file
audioFileName = @"recordingTestFile";
recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.caf", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER, audioFileName] ;

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];
err = nil;

recorder = nil;
recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recorderSettings error:&err];

//prepare to record
[recorder setDelegate:self];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

// start recording
[recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 4];//Maximum recording time : 10 seconds default
NSLog(@"Recroding Started");
}
```

MP3 is playing like following.

```
-(void) mp3PlayerLock: (NSString*) fileName {
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"mp3"];

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSError *error;

if(self.playerLock != nil && [self.playerLock isPlaying])
    [self.playerLock stop];

self.playerLock = nil;
self.playerLock = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                                                           error:&error];
self.playerLock.numberOfLoops = 0;
self.playerLock.delegate  = self;
[self.playerLock play];

}
```

I don't know what the reason is. Could you please help me?
Thanks,

Comment: You mean that the device volume turns down permanently as you play any recorded sound with the above method or the volume is down for recordings only?

Comment: Yes, once this happens, it keeps maintaining the reduced volume even though I play mp3 files.

Comment: Try this `[self.playerLock setVolume:1.0];` You may  also wish to set the value for volume in your `RecorderSettings`